# Bend UVs to follow a non-quad mesh

Tags: uv

How can I adjust the mapping so it follows this kind of topology?
[image]

Comment: do you need a curve to follow in UV_Editor or you want to make this flat in UV_Editor?

Comment: @MohammadHosseinJamshidi I need UVs to follow the curvature of the mesh, without using fiddly manual workflow like adjusting the UVs using proportional tool